# Was the question "etc. etc. usage" closed correctly?

Tags: discussion, question-closure

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544518/etc-etc-usage) was closed as being "opinion-based". But I thought that usage questions were on-topic for this site. After all, the asker says "Is there any rule…", not "How do you personally feel about…". Should it not have been closed?

Comment: Because the answer to the question “is there any rule” is “no”, the question is indeed opinion-based and was correctly closed. EL&U discusses the foundational structure of English, the nuts and bolts, morphology, syntax, orthography, phonology, etymology, etc. We are the “Lang” part of “Lit and Lang”; the “Lit” part is out of scope. The Q&A format of our site limits our ability to serve questions of style.

Comment: If it weren't closed for that reason, I would have voted to close it for "Needs more focus." Essentially, it's also a list request—mainly because the question is so poor and unfocused, and it gives no context at all (meaning another reason for closure would be "Needs detail or focus.". As such, any number of different styles could apply.